# How can I expose owners and managers in CiviVolunteer?

Tags: wordpress, civivolunteer

We have implemented CiviVolunteer to manage our 30 projects across 118 volunteers.

The positives:

- Projects are linked via Activities in sympathy with the overall CiviCRM design philosophy.
- Once two bug fixes were applied, it now works as specified - all good.

The negatives:

- The Volunteer subclass of Individual has popped up but is not used by
  CiviVolunteer for the actual volunteers. This is a bit confusing and
  instructions in our User Guide (thank you Echo Plugins for Knowledge
  Base for Documents and FAQs) are the way that we have dealt with
  this.
- The Volunteer reports don't expose the two relationships (Owner
  or Manager).
- The overall reporting system of CiviCRM doesn't appear to
  support (out of the box) summarisation of rows (e.g. a count of rows,
  a sum of values from a row, etc.).

Sounds like a lot of negatives, but we are using CiviVolunteer and are achieving a deal of acceptance from our users.

As requested in the guidelines, that's our story.

**Now the question**, how can I gain access to the two relationships (Owner and Manager) so that I can show the name of the owner and the manager on volunteer reports?

Regards,

Rob.

CiviCRM 5.4.1
PHP 7.1.24
CiviVolunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1
WordPress 4.9.8

Comment: Hi Rob - welcome. Good write up - i would note that the Q+A concept for SE really lends itself to a single question per .. well question. So I would encourage you to calve off 2/ and 3/ to separate tickets and reference them back to this one for the overview.